# Let F:$\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$-function, with $\lim_{|x|\to\ ∞}\frac{F(x)}{|x|^2}=0$,

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $F\colon\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$-function, with $\displaystyle\lim_{|x|\to\ ∞}\frac{F(x)}{|x|^2}=0$. Can we write $|F(x)|\leq C(1+|x|^a)$ for some $a$ such that $1 \leq a<2$?

Actually, I know that the order of $F(X)$ is less than $|X|^2$, but how can I prove that? I attempted to use Taylor formula, but I am not sure whether it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. if $n=1$ we can find a $C^{1}$function $f$ such that $f(x)=\frac {x^{2}} {\log x}$ for  $|x|>2$. In this case there is no such constant $C$.

Note that $\frac {x^{2}} {x^{a}\log x} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ for any $a<2$.

Comment: Thanks. So what if I say $|F(x)|\leq m+n|x|^a)$ for some $a$ such that $1 \leq a<2$, m, n are some constants.

Comment: Then the answer is YES. @DavidMao